# Custom cordova plugin (Windows 10) : ReferenceError when calling native code

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, windows-phone, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I've been writing a small custom plugin for my Ionic 2 app to get the device uptime since last system boot.

It's working well on Android and iOS but I'm struggling to make it work on Windows Phone 10.

I'm getting the following error when trying to call my Windows Runtime Component :

> Exception calling native with command :: Uptime :: getUptime  ::exception=ReferenceError: 'Environment' is undefined

This is the Windows Runtime Cmponent (C#), and it's compiled in a Uptime.winmd file :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Uptime
{
    public sealed class Uptime
    {
        public static string getUptime()
        {
            return (Environment.TickCount & Int32.MaxValue).ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

The Uptime.winmd is referenced in the Plugin.xml (as well as the other native implementation for iOS and Android, and the other js scripts) :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<plugin id="cordova-plugin-uptime" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <name>Uptime</name>
    <js-module name="Uptime" src="www/Uptime.js">
        <clobbers target="cordova.plugins.Uptime"/>
    </js-module>
    <platform name="android">
        <config-file parent="/*" target="res/xml/config.xml">
            <feature name="Uptime">
                <param name="android-package" value="cordova.plugin.uptime.Uptime"/>
            </feature>
        </config-file>
        <config-file parent="/*" target="AndroidManifest.xml"/>
        <source-file src="src/android/Uptime.java" target-dir="src/cordova-plugin-uptime/Uptime"/>
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <config-file parent="/*" target="config.xml">
            <feature name="Uptime">
                <param name="ios-package" value="Uptime"/>
            </feature>
        </config-file>
        <source-file src="src/ios/Uptime.m"/>
    </platform>
    <platform name="windows">
        <js-module src="src/windows/UptimeProxy.js" name="UptimeProxy">
            <merges target="" />
        </js-module>
        <framework src="src/windows/Uptime.winmd" custom="true" target="phone"/>
    </platform>
</plugin>
```

The Uptime.winmd is called from the UptimeProxy.js :

```
cordova.commandProxy.add("Uptime",{
    getUptime:function(successCallback, errorCallback, strInput) {
        var res = Uptime.Uptime.getUptime();
        if(res.indexOf("Error") == 0) {
            errorCallback(res);
        }
        else {
            successCallback(res);
        }
    }
});
```

Which is itself called from the Uptime.js :

```
var exec = require('cordova/exec');

exports.getUptime = function() {
    return new Promise(function(success, error) {
        exec(success, error, "Uptime", "getUptime", []);
    })
};
```

Which is itself called from my application (from a (click) event so it's not a problem of not yet loaded dependencies).

The Uptime.js works well with Android and iOS.

The UptimeProxy.js is definitely called since I can see logs placed before

`var res = Uptime.Uptime.getUptime();`

I'm generating the project with the Ionic/cordova CLI and then deploying on my device with VS2015.

Ionic info :

```
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.4.0
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.14
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.7
Ionic App Scripts Version: 0.
ios-deploy version: Not insta
ios-sim version: Not installe
OS: Windows 10
Node Version: v6.9.1
Xcode version: Not installed
```

The compilation for both the plugin and the app is set to "Debug - any CPU".

I'm surely doing something wrong, but I checked other plugins using C# code for WP10 and didn't spotted a difference.

And since the cordova documentation is far from exhaustive, I don't have any clue on what to do.

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance and don't hesitate if you need more info about my setup.

Comment: Did you ever get this working? Facing similar issues

Comment: Sadly no, I had to disable the feature on WP.